# Custom page number in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, customize

I want to customize the table of content. I want acknowledgment, a list of tables, figures, and a chapter displayed as in the picture below.

[image: University expectation]

I am using the below code in the document class book.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage{fncychap}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase %  also for "Table of content" etc.
\ChNameVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering}
\ChNumVar{\normalsize\mdseries}
\ChTitleVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering}

% following is inspired by pages 8-9 of the manual of the fncychap package
% Adding of \vspace{-3cm} to move up the word "CHAPTER" and his number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
\vspace{-3cm}\CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\thechapter\par\nobreak 
\vskip 10\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{% 
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{% 
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}{\mdseries}

\centerline{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CHAPTER}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\newpage 

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

hdhdhdhdhhddh
\section{Motivation}

\section{methods}

hdhdhdh

\end{document}
```

But the output I am getting is as below. I want appropriate page numering which is Acknowldemnt page 2, list of tables 4 etc..
I know I can use `\chapter` in front of acknowledgment but I dont want to identify it as a chapter and have written chapter number. Also `\chapter` does not work for `\listoftables`. Please help.

[image: Code]